# trigger option select and get value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a select menu which has a list of number options.

Rooms is an array which can contain multiple room objects. Each room object contains a number for adults and children.

When a user clicks on a dropdown menu for children or adults how do I do I get the users selected option and parse that to scope function so I can update the rooms.children for that particular room property?

I'm currently using ng-click but that function doesn't even get called.

[Plunkr example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ulch45h0ofAOZQ5B29FP?p=preview)

Comment: For select and options, you'd better use [ng-options](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-model to bind the selected value to a scope property: http://plnkr.co/edit/vfl16rS1XyjhbesqVYDi?p=preview

You can also use ng-options instead of ng-repeat on the options, see: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: Thanks but how do I trigger a function when an adult or childs value has been changed?

Comment: @user971824 Try `ng-change`